# Avoid to build template headers in shared library

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, build

I have a shared library which has headers including classes with template functions. Whenever I make a change in template functions, I have to do `make clean` and `make` again to "update" the `.so` file.  Is there a way to avoid building the shared library every time I change template functions in headers?

Comment: I don't quite understand you're asking for, if the headers containing these function templates are included by the files being compiled into the shared library, then the library will be rebuilt when you modify the headers, and it should if the function templates are being used by it. If the function templates are not being used by the code compiled into the shared lib, then you need to maybe move them into a separate set of headers so modifying those doesn't trigger a rebuild.

Comment: How did you construct the dependencies in your makefile? If you naively said every source file depends on every header file, then yes, you need to rebuild everything every time you change anything. If you used a tool that generates dependencies based on `#include` statements, then you only need to rebuild the things that depend on the changed files. No tool that I know of looks so deep in your code to see if the specific definitions you are using have changed. You might as well recompile.